# Azure CLI Command to list VMs with 'Y' as the third character in their name

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am writing a script that collects all VMs across all subscriptions, having the letter 'Y' as the third character in their name.

Already tried the command below, no luck however:

`az vm list --output table --query "[?name[2]=='Y']"`

It should return all the VMs in the subscription, with 'Y' being their third letter. However, the command results with an empty list.
Without the query (`az vm list --output table`), it works just fine, however I'd like the scope to be the tenant, not just the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the VM names with third letter as `Y` for one subscription I used the below script.

```c
#!/bin/bash
 
# Get the list of VM names
vm_names=$(az vm list --query "[].name" --output tsv)
 
# Filter and display VM names with 'y' as the third letter
echo "VM names with 'y' as the third letter:"
for vm_name in $vm_names; do
    third_letter=$(echo "$vm_name" | cut -c3)
    if [ "$third_letter" == "y" ]; then
        echo "$vm_name"
    fi
done
```

***Output***:

[image]

In my environment I have 1 subscription so to get virtual machine name with `y` as third latter across all subscription modify the script like below:

```c
#!/bin/bash
 
# Get a list of all the Azure subscriptions in the tenant
subscriptions=$(az account list --query "[].id" --output tsv)
 
# Iterate through each subscription
for subscription in $subscriptions; do
    echo "Subscription: $subscription"
 
    # Set the current subscription for Azure CLI
    az account set --subscription $subscription
 
    # Get the list of VM names in the current subscription
    vm_names=$(az vm list --query "[].name" --output tsv)
 
    # Filter and display VM names with 'y' as the third letter
    echo "VM names with 'y' as the third letter in subscription $subscription:"
    for vm_name in $vm_names; do
        third_letter=$(echo "$vm_name" | cut -c3)
        if [ "$third_letter" == "y" ]; then
            echo "$vm_name"
        fi
    done
 
    echo
done
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)